# What is the technique to create a blob effect with shapes in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes

Can anyone please guide me about the exact technique that is used to create this blob effect, I am trying to create a logo design.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Metaball script by Hiroyuki Sato. ([Download available here](http://shspage.com/aijs/en), along with some other very useful scripts).

Simply draw some circles, select them and run the script. Done.

[image]

[image]

Comment: "Meatball" script? ;)

Comment: I think meatball is better :)

Comment: hey :) Thank you that helps. meetball script is better indeed.